# UPDATING single value array - PHP - MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form that collect and insert data in a MySQL table using array.
Here is the example of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="data_one[]">
<input type="text" name="data_two[]">
```

The table collects data of number of books a person own. Let say John has three books, it will record the data in this manner:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| id    | owner_id | data_one | data_two |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1     |  john23  | book_1   | book_1   |
| 2     | john23   | book_2   | book_2   |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now the problem comes when I am trying to update the record. 
Here is my code for updating the record:

```
if(is_array($this->data_one)){

  foreach($this->data_one AS $key => $value) {

                $query_2 = "INSERT INTO

                  ". $this->table_name . "

                  SET
                  owner_id = :owner_id,
                  data_one = :data_one,
                  data_two = :data_two

                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

                  data_one = :data_one,
                  data_two = :data_two
                  ";

                  $stmt_2 = $this->conn->prepare($query_2);

                  $this->data_one = $value;
                  $this->data_two = $this->data_two;
                  $this->owner_id = $this->owner_id;

                  $stmt_2->bindParam(':data_one', $this->data_one);
                  $stmt_2->bindParam(':data_two', $this->data_two[$key]);
                  $stmt_2->bindParam(':owner_id', $this->owner_id[$key]);

                  $stmt_2->execute();
     }
```

And I retrieve the data to be updated using this code:

```
if($_POST){

$data_class->data_one=$_POST['data_one'];
$data_class->data_two=$_POST['data_two'];
$data_class->owner_id=$_POST['owner_id'];

if($data_class->update()){
  echo "ok";
  } else{
    echo "not ok";
  }
}


<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?id={$owner_id");?>" method="post">
<?php

$stmt = $data_class->retrieve_data_about_books();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  extract($row);
 echo '<td><input type="hidden"  name="owner_id[]"value="'.strtoupper($row["owner_id"]).'"/></td>'
 <td><input type="text"  name="data_one[]"value="'.strtoupper($row["data_one"]).'"/></td>

 <td><input type="number" step=0.01 name="data_two[]"   value="'.$row["data_two"].'"/></td>';

}
}else{
}
?>

<button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```

When I am updating only one record, that where the problem comes in, it would not update, but if there is a multiple record it can update, even if I am only one of the two record.

Additional scenario:
Let say, a user have two books, his record will look like this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| id    | owner_id | data_one | data_two |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1     |  john23  | book_1   | book_1   |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2     | john23   | book_2   | book_2   |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

but when a user only owns one book his record will look like this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| id    | owner_id | data_one | data_two |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3     |  jack22  | book_1   | book_1   |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

By the way, data_one is the title of the book, data_two is the genre, and owner_id is the identifier of the book owner.
the problem occurred when I update the single record using the code above.

Comment: If you want to **update** a row, why not issue an `UPDATE` query? Additionally, what are the primary keys to your table? If you don't use them in the `UPDATE` query, it's pretty obvious that more rows will be updated

Comment: That is the initial idea, but there are situation that a user acquired a new book, so when that happens, they can easily add new book(INSERT), if it still not exist, and UPDATE it it already is.

Comment: What is data_two?

Comment: what do you mean? @Strawberry , ok let say data_one is the title of the book and data_two is the genre.

Comment: But wouldn't (book_)genre be a separate table? Maybe this redundancy is at the heart of your difficulty

Comment: No, I do not think that is the case, the table is just a list of books that a certain individual owns. An individual can have or own multiple books over time, so they can add and update whenever they need to.